# Webcam streaming to red5 and embed to website

Tags: stream, webcam, red5

I'm trying to build an application which allows users to livestream stream from theirs webcam.

My main problem is I don't know how connect  this [webcam script](https://github.com/AF83/webcam-streaming) to the red5 streaming server and how to embed it to the website.
I will be thankful for any guidance.

Comment: The readme on that project gives an example of how to set things up. The only thing you need to do is install red5 and modify the urls in the example to point at your red5 server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must send stream to some RED5 RTMP chanel and connect the flash script to the chanel via RTMP to get stream. Next, you must have application in red5 side to use rtmp protocol for streaming try use oflaDemo application which is in default build and look how it works in it.

But streaming is not so hard here is some guides how to do it:

[Simple guide with OlfaDemo](http://blog.endpoint.com/2012/04/streaming-live-with-red5-media-server.html)

[Guide 2](http://blog.endpoint.com/2013/03/streaming-live-with-red5-media.html)

I hope this helps.